# leaflet fullscreen clustermarker Disappear

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer, leaflet.markercluster

I build a simple `js` app:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
                spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
                showCoverageOnHover: false,
                zoomToBoundsOnClick: true,
                removeOutsideVisibleBounds:true
});

for (var i = 0; i < randomGeoPoints.length; i++) {
            var a = randomGeoPoints[i];
            var title = "pippo";
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title,icon:lightIcon });

            marker.bindPopup(title);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
        }

map.addLayer(markers);
```

With [these](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/) [two](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.fullscreen/issues/)
and a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8l7RFGlGpozDLalW0DWY)

When I exit full screen mode my cluster points layer disappears. But when I return the layer is there.
I'm using Safari desktop browser, in Safari mobile (iPad) it does not happen.

I test with no cluster but with simple points layer and it's OK.
The Plunker demo instead works.

Are there any bugs about this ?

Comment: Your Plunker works fine for me on Safari 11.1.2 (macOS 10.13.6)

Comment: Yes, but in my web site not works. I will think to change plugin. Thanks.